# I'm unable to add new options to drop down menus - form fields freeze on clicking the mouse

Tags: configuration

I'm just installing civicrm for the first time under drupal 9. On my very similar test system on my home pc I can add new items to the menus such as defining membership types. But on my real system it only works for the very first definition. For the second I can add text to the Name field but on clicking the mouse no other fields are accessible and even the Name field is frozen. So the only to do is cancel.There are no messages in the log. I see the same problem when adding entries to contribute/payment methods. It seems to happen when there is already some entries in there. I looked to see if there was a way to import/export configuration as a workaround but that doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Can you error log or drupal watchdog to see detail about the error?

Comment: I've managed to solve it, after finding that if I changed the drupal theme it then worked. To get it work with my normal theme I found I had to go into drupal/appearance where I found a new section for civicrm. There I changed the civicrm admin theme to my normal admin theme as it had been using it had been set to default.